# Extracting the coordinates of a point one receives from \draw with $-- ++$

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am having problems with the coordinates of `\draw[->] (.:.)-- ++ (.:.);` - I need to extract the coordinates of the second point of the vector. How do I do that? In other words: Is there an option for adding vectors in polarcoordinates (without having to use all the bulky formulas)?

The reason I need to find the coordinates of e.g. `\draw[->] (x:y)-- ++ (a:b);` is that $x,y,a,b$ are random numbers and I want to draw another arrow starting from where `\draw[->] (x:y)-- ++ (a:b);` ended.

Comment: The moment a point is placed, its coordinates are converted into canvas coordinates which are in `pt` relative to the absolute origin of the enclosing box.

Comment: What do you mean by “Is there an option for adding vectors in polarcoordinates (without having to use all the bulky formulas)?”

Comment: Please, try to add a compilable example asking exactly what you need to obtain... I have to admit I am not understanding the question.

Comment: `coordinate[pos=1] (A)` in same line as `\draw` (before the semicolon) to get the end point.

Comment: As @JohnKormylo said, just place a coordinate at `(x:y)+(a:b)`, say `\draw[->](x:y)--++(a:b) coordinate (abc);` And then you can do `\draw (abc) -- …;`.